# Control Panel not showing

Tags: windows-vista

Whenever I select 'Control Panel' from my taskbar all it comes up with is an open window with nothing in it. I'm running Vista and have recently turned of UAC (if this makes a difference). Can anybody help me to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click in the blank space you see and select "Arrange Icons By >> Name".  It's possible they are just off the edge of the window.

Are the various *.CPL files still there? Deleting them would presumably produce this result.  If they're still there, you can just run them to get the same effect as using Control Panel.